# Azure SQL How to Check Partition Logic

Tags: database-design, azure-sql-database

I have table where i have partitioned it by day , my table

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    date DATE,
     /// other fields
   
) on dailyPartitionScheme(date)
```

When i do the query

```
Select * from test where date = {d '2023-05-30'}
```

Will it go the respective partition or it will scan whole table ? How i can verify this which partition it isscanning ?

I have three more filters which will present in all my queries i.e `dep_id , id and uuid`

Should i create clustered index on these 3 fields to have optimal query performance ? Do i need to include date also in my index ?